# WCF Server autostart while windows log in

Tags: c#, wcf, file-transfer, autologin

I would like to create a WCF application to copy huge files from server to client. My problem is 'How can I auto start the server application upon server machine log on ?'. It is aimed to a small office intranet application and all the machine running on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the WCF Server as a window Service you can get it to start automatically from the Windows Services Panel.

However, I would advise to set the start-up mode to delayed start as I have encountered some issues in the past with the automatic start.

Answer (score 0):

What is windows log in? There is only user log in. If you need service host application to start after computer boot you need to [host it in Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx). If you need some process to start after user log in you can create simple console application and add it to `Startup` (applications running after user log in).

Anyway creating WCF service for copying files is a global nonsense. It looks like everybody things that WCF is technology for large data transfers. It is not - especially it is not a technology for file transfers. Use shared drives and normal file copying - custom batch file can be added on each machine into `Startup` or install FTP (part of IIS which is available on Windows 7 Ultimate).